# How to bring word application to the front in vb.NET

Tags: vb.net, ms-word

I am using winforms and when I try to open a word document programmatically it goes behind all the opened windows randomly. How can I bring it to the front? Following is my code.

```
    Dim pAppWord As Object = CreateObject("Word.Application")
```

'//do my stuff

```
    pAppWord.Visible = True
    pAppWord.Application.Activewindow = True
    '//pAppWord.Active() found this online but throws an error
    pAppWord.WindowState = vbNormal
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was

```
pAppWord.Activate()
```

Answer (score 0):

This doen't seem trivial... maybe this one helps: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/vblanguage/thread/fd9215cf-0893-4c61-886c-5d22fa7c2055

Comment: Looks like it has what I need. I'll let you know as soon as I tried it.Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

If you've added or opened a document (e.g. wordOb.Documents.Add) then you can simply pass `wordOb.ActiveWindow.Hwnd` to the Windows API function `SetForegroundWindow`.